# remove some XML line in a org.w3c.dom.Document

Tags: java, xml

I have a `org.w3c.dom.Document` which contains XML, how I can do if I want to take from that Document only some information enclosed in some tags?
Example (I want only tag included in `<catalog>`     `<catalog/>`)

```xml
//Some VALUES

    <CATALOG>
      <CD>
      <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
      <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
      <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
      <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
      <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
      <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
      <ORACLE>
      select * from scott.dept;
      </ORACLE>
      </CD>
      <CD>
      <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
      <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
      <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
      <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
      <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
      <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
      </CD>
      <ORACLE>
      begin
      htp.p('This is the test data');
      end;
      </ORACLE>
      </CD>
    </CATALOG>
//OTHER VALUES
```

I have found that Document have method getElementsByTag name that is a NodeList  how I can transform this in a Document?

Comment: What is a java document? Do you mean some instance of `org.w3c.dom.Document`? Or is it an XML document? If the latter, what did you try?

Comment: And what exaclty do you want? A ``Document`` with some elements removed? Or do you want to use specific values from that ``Document`` in your java code?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post it please. We are here to help you, not make you the whole code.

Comment: @f1sh i want the same Document with some elements removed. For now i don't know how to start..please give me an input

Comment: Also, note that <catalog> is not the same as <CATALOG>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have used this code:

```
Node elem = null;
    NodeList lista=doc.getElementsByTagName("Items");
                for(int i=0;i<lista.getLength();i++){
                elem = lista.item(i);
                }

                NodeList lista2=doc.getElementsByTagName("MoreOffersUrl");
                for(int i=0;i<lista2.getLength();i++){
                   Node elem2=lista2.item(i);
                    elem.removeChild(elem2);
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend writing an [XPath expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html), which returns all nodes you want to remove, then iterating through the result and removing the nodes from the DOM.

A demonstration (not tested, also I assume your root element is called `ROOT`):

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "/ROOT/CATALOG/CD/*[self::COMPANY or self::PRICE]";
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(expression, doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

for (Node n: nodes) {
    n.getParentNode().removeChild(n);
}
```